# Java applet to upload files and folders while keeping directory stucture intact

Tags: java, file-upload, applet, sftp

the following code is for uploading files and folders to a server(SFTP). i m trying to keep the folder structure intact i.e. C:\temp\test\file.txt becomes /home/www/javauploads/**temp/test/file.txt** on the server. but when i run it the files all upload but the folders and files are just dumped on the server without any structure at all and the file names appear like this (C3NXXV~9) is there a way to upload the files and folders while keeping the structure and file names intact, thanks. `

```
    private static void processDir(File dir) throws JSchException, SftpException {
    String SFTPHOST = "*****.com";
    int    SFTPPORT = ***;
    String SFTPUSER = "****";
    String SFTPPASS = "*****";
    String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "/home/www/javauploads/";`Session     session     = null;
    Channel     channel     = null;
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER,SFTPHOST,SFTPPORT);
    session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect();

    channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();
    channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
    channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);


    if (dir.isDirectory()){
        channelSftp.mkdir(dir.toString());
        System.out.println("[Directory] : " + dir);
    }else{
        channelSftp.put(dir.toString());
        System.out.println("[File] : " + dir);
    }
    channelSftp.exit();
    session.disconnect();
}

private static void traverse(File dir) throws JSchException, SftpException {

    processDir(dir);

    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            traverse(new File(dir, children[i]));
        }
    }

}`
```

Comment: Is this problem still open? If so, it might help to know the client and server system, and the SSH server. If not, please post the solution you found.

Answer (score 0):

First (unrelated to your problem), you should not start a new session and channel for each file or directory - open the session and channel once, and reuse it for all the file uploads. This will be much faster, since each session opening takes some roundtrips and some complicated cryptographic calculations. Opening a channel takes another roundtrip.

Then, take a look on how [ChannelSftp.put(String)](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#put%28java.lang.String%29) works. It takes the remote file name as argument, and returns an OutputStream, into which you then can write your data. You are not using the OutputStream, which means that no upload really will occur.

I suppose you want [ChannelSftp.put(String, String)](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) - this will take a local and remote file name, and upload the contents of the local file, creating a remote file (or overwriting it, if it already exists).

Also, there may be a problem that [dir.toString()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toString%28%29) returns a file name in the local naming convention (i.e. separated by `\` on Windows systems), while you need the names separated by `/`. You could use a simple `.replace('\\', '/')`, I think.

This does not really explain your observation, though - which SSH server are you using, on which system?

Comment: the client is a windows machine while the server is bsd. thanks